# amixer controls won't get anything on my development board

Tags: linux, arm, alsa

I am trying to set volume on the minilinux system with amixer controls in development board,but it won't get anything.

```
~ # amixer
~ # 
~ # amixer controls
~ #
```

I have tried to create a plugin by create this file in "/etc/asound.conf"as this [How_to_use_softvol_to_control_the_master_volume](https://alsa.opensrc.org/How_to_use_softvol_to_control_the_master_volume)said ,by type in this

```
    pcm.softvol {
    type            softvol
    slave {
        pcm         "hw:0,0"
    }
    control {
        name        "softctl"
        card        0
    }
}
```

but when testing it ,give me this error:

```
/etc # speaker-test -D softvol -c 2 &                                                                   
/etc # 
speaker-test 1.1.5

Playback device is softvol
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM softvol
Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

when I changed the asound.conf to something like this:

```
    pcm.softvol {
    type        hw
    card        0
    device      0       
}
```

then exac " speaker-test -D softvol -c 2 &  " the headphone have that pink noise.
This is really weird that I can play and record excpet control the volume. New to this,no idea what to do next.

Comment: Apparently, the driver does not create any controls, and the softvol plugin is not compiled. Ask the driver author and the admin of your machine.

Comment: Thanks,after created a slave and softvol plugin it works.